# Retrieving thumbnail from video - Objective C

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I have an application that uploads videos into a server and now what I am trying to create is a news feed to display those video post but by a thumbnail or frame of the video.  So that once the user clicks the thumbnail the video will play.

I have the following code used to grab the video from the server and play it:

```
- (void)openVideo {

    NSString *videoURLString = @"http://myite.com/dev/iphone/uploads/t69566.mov";
    NSURL *videoURL = [NSURL URLWithString:videoURLString];
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayerView = [[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL] autorelease];

    [self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerView];

}
```

Now of coarse I am gong to make `openVideo` dynamic with the population of video post but I am stuck on taking this video and grabbing a frame or thumbnail and displaying it.

Suggestions? thoughts?

UPDATE:

I want to take a thumbnail from a video taken from server.  which actually brings me to a question.

When the user first uploads the video, would it be better to just create a thumbnail there and upload it to my server and just associate that with the video on grabbing them to populate a news feed type?

Comment: You want to get the thumbnail on the server? (So you can download thumb image and then video)

Comment: I have been able to get the thumbnail from the video directly but it can be extremely slow so I would caution that form of grabbing a thumbnail.

Comment: Best if the server takes the thumb from the video. No point uploading a thumb unless you must for some reason.

Comment: @Wain ya that what I assumed.  So how can I grab that from a video being streamed from my server?  What should my approach be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it using the `AVAssetImageGenerator`. Rough code, copied and pasted from a working project (but might not be properly isolated):

- `_thumbnailView` is an `UIImageView` to display the thumbnail.
- `_activityView` is a `UIActivityIndicatorView` that gets hidden when the thumbnail finishes loading.

  ```
  AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [[AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:movieURL] retain];
  AVAssetImageGenerator *_generator;
  _generator = [[AVAssetImageGenerator assetImageGeneratorWithAsset:playerItem.asset] retain];
  [playerItem release];

  AVAssetImageGeneratorCompletionHandler handler = ^(CMTime requestedTime, CGImageRef image, CMTime actualTime, AVAssetImageGeneratorResult result, NSError *error) {
      if (result == AVAssetImageGeneratorSucceeded) {
          UIImage *thumb = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image];
          [_thumbnailView setImage:thumb forState:UIControlStateNormal];
      } else {
          DLog(@"%s - error: %@", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, error);
      }
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
          _thumbnailView.hidden = NO;
          _playButton.hidden = NO;
          [_activityView stopAnimating];
      });
  };

  [_generator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(30,30)]] completionHandler:handler];
  ```

Back to your question, in my opinion, a server side generated thumbnail is usually better, as servers have way more processing power. Also, in order to get this thumbnail you need to start downloading the actual video from the server.

Finally, not that you pass a `CMTime` parameter including a call to `CMTimeMakeWithSeconds()`. This might prove problematic, as you can easily hit a blank frame. This is why we are using 30 as the parameter, so we avoid that situation in our videos.

Comment: Okay pgb thank you so much for the response.  So with my `openVideo` method, I am a little confused on when would I call the code you gave me? After `[self presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:moviePlayerView];` which then brings me to a question.  Since I can only do this without downloading the video from server.  What I am trying to accomplish is think of Facebook how it shows the video frame first and than once you click on it, it than opens the stream.  Am I unable to do this without actually storing the thumbnail on my server first?

Comment: You should use the thumbnail generator first, and use that image to create a button the user can tap. Once he taps that button (with the thumbnail) you can call your `openVideo` method that will take over the user screen with the video player.

Comment: Okay ya that makes sense so when trying to use your code I come across a few issues.  Firstly I am defining a test button using `UIImageView *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
` and than from there changing values to match my code.  Issue is with the `cache` section ->`[UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumb) writeToURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:cachedFilePath] atomically:NO];`has no valid identifier, to be more exact: `cachedFilePath` does not exist and I am not sure what that is suppose to be?

Comment: I just removed that line. It's a recommended addition though: store the file in a cache, so if your user accesses the same video again, you don't need to regenerate the thumbnail.

Comment: so okay now so since I will be populating this in a way like a newsfeed, its sorta slow.  How can I speed it up or whatnot.  What I mean is the button takes a little bit to show up and I assume thats because of the `[_generator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(30,30)]] completionHandler:handler];
`

Comment: I don't think you can speed it up. Try different values for `CMTimeMakeWithSeconds` though. Maybe 0 instead of 30 will download less from the video (docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreMedia/Reference/CMTime/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CMTimeMakeWithSeconds)). I would also try to have server side thumbnails in your case.

Comment: quick question for you how would I call a custom `completionHandler` on completion `[_generator generateCGImagesAsynchronouslyForTimes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSValue valueWithCMTime:CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(30,30)]] completionHandler:handler];` to a method?

Comment: In the example, `handler` is a block. Inside the `dispatch_async`, where we display the thumbnail, you could call any method you want.